# OperationalError when trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL server in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a task that asks:

You have two abstract reports made available to you on a PostgreSQL server located at: postgres://candidate.company.org/company

username = candidate   password = abc

So I used this code to try connect to the database:

```
import psycopg2 as db
conn = db.connect(host='postgres://candidate.suade.org/company', database='randomname', user='candidate', password='abc', port='5432')
```

I received the following error message:

OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres://candidate.suade.org/suade" to address: Unknown host

My experience of connecting to databases is limited. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I just tried using host='candidate.company.org/company' and got the same error message. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `postgres://candidate.company.org/company` is a DB URL, not hostname. It consists of protocol, hostname and db name.

Comment: It is just `host='candidate.company.org'`

Comment: Great thanks, that seemed to work (not throw an error message at least). I had to also change database='randomname' to 'postgresql'

Comment: Not completely sure i am connected. But if I am, any idea how i would access the  'two abstract reports '? That way I will know

Comment: What are the reports constructed as, tables ?